# Obtaining line number in stack trace on solaris

Tags: c, solaris, callstack, backtrace, line-numbers

In my C++ program I have a function that prints the current callstack at runtime, like this:

```
int printFct(uintptr_t pc, int sig, void* usrarg)
{
   Dl_info dlip;

   if (dladdr((void *)pc, &dlip))
   {
      char buf[100+1]; *buf= 0;

      if (cplus_demangle(dlip.dli_sname, buf, 100) == 0)
         printf("  %s\n", buf);
      else
         printf("  %s\n", dlip.dli_sname);

      return 0;
   }

   return -1;
}

void printStack()
{
   ucontext_t context;

   if (getcontext(&context) != 0)
      return;

   walkcontext(&context, &printFct, 0);
}
```

This works great, however I am not given any line number. Is there a way to also print the line numbers for the corresponding functions called?

[edit] to clarify: I do **not** want to write the stack to a *file* to analyze it later, I want to print it on stdout during runtime, so the commandline `gaddr2line` is not an option.

Comment: Line numbers in stacktraces ... retrieving these requires parsing the _debug information_ in the binary. Meaning unless you've compiled with `-g` _and_ haven't stripped the object files, this must fail. It's also expensive to do, more so even than `dladdr()`. Could ask, in short, why are you trying to reinvent DTrace ? And why are you insisting on line numbers even though those incur a high performance penalty ?

Comment: Actually, the line numbers would be a minor, cosmetic thing. its completely okay and helpful without them. the function will never be used in production, although the binary *is* compiled with `-g`. what i'm trying to do is track down a memory leak, and I hoped to find growing but never free'd lists, and therefore i would need a callstack, to see where it is coming from. since, however, i did not find the leak yet, i also dont actually need the line number as of now. i just thouhgt it would be a nice function to have, to use for debugging ocasionally. thus, performance is not an issue.

Comment: Tracking down memory leaks using DTrace is a pretty typical showcase, https://blogs.oracle.com/chrisg/entry/using_dtrace_to_track_down or https://blogs.oracle.com/openomics/entry/investigating_memory_leaks_with_dtrace for examples. Yes, slightly cumbersome with C++. But easier than writing your own allocator instrumentation.

Comment: Thanks for this alternate approach. I will look into this.